# Ошибка при отправке curl запроса к crm

Tags: laravel, post, curl, https, crm

Всем привет. При отправке лидов в crm под названием AMO выбрасывается такая ошибка: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to mydomain.amocrm.ru port 443: Connection timed out. Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну или проверяйте адрес, или давайте больше информации и кода. Гадать на кофейной гуще тут никто не будет...